# Node.js Express | JQuery Nothing happens on client when getting a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, postgresql

I want to receive on an HTML5 website JSON from a PostgreSQL database. So, on the server side I use node-postgres module for DB connection and also express module for communication.

The problem is that in the html i am not seeing any alert when getting the data from the server. The alert isn't even thrown.

this is how my code is so far, for anyone that could help:

serverside

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/data', function(req, res){
   var pg = require('pg'); 

            var conString = "postgres://postgres:postgres2@localhost/spots";

            var client = new pg.Client(conString);
            client.connect(function(err) {
              if(err) {
                res.send('could not connect to postgres');
              }
              client.query('SELECT * from spots_json where id=3276', function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                 res.send('error running query'); 
                }
                res.set("Content-Type", 'text/javascript'); // i added this to avoid the "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html" message
                res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows[0].json));
                              client.end();
              });
            }); 

});

app.listen(3000);
```

clientside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"></meta>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" ></script>

    <script>

   $.get('http://localhost:3000/data?callback=?',{}, function(data){
       alert(data.type); 
   },"json");                  

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The client is now executed on `http://localhost:8888/prueba/prueba.html`

Im getting a js with the following Response:

```
"{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-2.994783,43.389217]}"
```

The Response can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi4c5pqnbctf548/pantallazo.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result.rows[0].json` is not an object, it is a string. You don't need to `stringify` it:

```
res.send(result.rows[0].json);
```

---

**Edit:**

If you use two servers on different ports you will need to use JSONP. jQuery makes this simple on the client side, but you will need to implement it in your server ([example](https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520357#file-server-js)):

```
if(req.query.callback) {
  res.send(req.query.callback + '(' + result.rows[0].json + ');');
} else {
  res.send(result.rows[0].json);
}
```

---

By the way, you need to `return` if you encounter an error in one of your callbacks to prevent subsequent code from being executed.

```
if(err) {
  res.end('error message');
  return;
  // Or shorter: return res.end('error message');
}
```

Comment: ok, i can see now in chrome's console that i am getting:
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-2.994783,43.389217]}

but the alert isn't still showing and i get the following error in chromes console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : :3000/data?callback=jsonp1383996982220:1

is the callback really necessary? if i dont use it i get the XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/data. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  error.